# Bringing up an unpleasant topic

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs

I'm new here so I hope I am doing this right.

I heard a phrasal verb (or an idiom, not sure) months ago, but I can't remember what it was and it's driving me crazy. Worse thing is I can't even remember how to say that thing in my own language so I can't look it up.

It was used in a context where two people had a disagreement about something. After their argument, they both cooled down somehow, but a third party brought up the unpleasant topic unintentionally. Then he sensed the tension between the two and asked "oh, did I .....?"

What could this phrasal verb/idiom be? I am sure it was not "the elephant in the room".

Thank you all in advance!
B

Comment: I'd say, "Oh, did I step in something?"

Comment: Thanks! The one I heard was touch a nerve though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options are:

- "*Stir up trouble*"
- "*Stir something up*"
- "*Touch a nerve*"
- "*Open old wounds*"

Comment: It was touch a nerve! Thanks a lot :)